# How to add navigation to this button in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making an app in React-Native and am trying to add navigation to the buttons I am adding. My question is how should I add navigation to them, as when I click on the buttons now they navigate to nothing?

```
<RedBtn
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({ searchMode: true });
        }}
        title={'Order delivered'}
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using for navigation?

If you are using nothing, you should use something like `react-navigation`, and then you will need to create routes and load your components from there.

Then you can just do

```
<RedBtn
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("SomeOtherPage")
        }}
        title={'Order delivered'}
      />
```

ref: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

You can probably do a little bit of navigation without using react-navigation by doing conditional rendering.